# is there a way to "mirror" react searchbar component in different place?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, algolia

I am using react-instantsearch library by Algolia.

I have multiple tab menu that each has its own search index(tab1="recipes", tab2="ingredients" etc.)

According to the docs, InstantSearch widget has to wrap all the other search widgets that means that my code has to be like this:

```
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient1} indexName="instant_search">
          <SearchBox />
          <Hits />
        </InstantSearch>
      </TabPanel>
```

Based on this I believe that I have to have my search component under the tab menu.

However I want to know if there is a way for me to somehow to "mirror" the search component and place the copy above my tabs menu and then somehow hide the original, but maintain the functionality.

[image: This is how I want it to look]

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is "multi-index" search. Inside your Instant Search component, you can specify multiple indexes for the search field to search. You could then have the state of your `<TabPanel>` component show the proper `<Index />` component.

The high-level use case is shown in [this doc](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/multi-index-search/react/)